# Launch FileMaker with fmp:// protocol in PHP script?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header, filemaker

On Windows, the "fmp://server_address/database_name" protocol works fine in any browser, IE included.

But when I try to execute it from with a PHP script, it works on every browser except IE:

```
$url = 'fmp://99.99.99.99/Database_Name';
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: text/html");
header("Location: $url");
```

IE just gives a "webpage cannot be displayed; some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed". Similar to what you'd expect if the fmp protocol wasn't in the registry, which it is, because the FileMaker installer put it there, and the fmp:// protocol does work fine if you type it into IE's address bar.

Any suggestions how to launch it from a PHP script for IE users?

Comment: security zone issue, perhaps, not allowing fmp:// urls in the internet zone, but allowing it at the address bar because (supposedly) users know what they're doing when they type in an address directly?

Comment: How would I address this to see if it helps?